# Add button to dockble windows in inventor?

Tags: .net, autodesk

I have made a tools. But it is not dockeble.  but I this code that make a dockbel windows. but do I add button to it that will run sub ?`

```
Dim oUserInterfaceMgr As UserInterfaceManager
        oUserInterfaceMgr = ThisApplication.UserInterfaceManager

        ' Create a new dockable window
        Dim oWindow As DockableWindow
        oWindow = oUserInterfaceMgr.DockableWindows.Add("SampleClientId6", "TestWindowInternalName6", "Test Window6")

        ' Get the hwnd of the dialog to be added as a child
        ' CHANGE THIS VALUE!
        Dim hwnd As Long
        hwnd = 4851096

        ' Add the dialog as a child to the dockable window
        oWindow.AddChild(hwnd)

        ' Don't allow docking to top and bottom
        oWindow.DisabledDockingStates = DockingStateEnum.kDockTop And DockingStateEnum.kDockBottom

        ' Make the window visible
        oWindow.Visible = True
```

how do I add button to it. And how do I add code that run when you click the button ?
`

I want to recreat my current tools into a dockbel windows

my current tools look like this

[image: My tools]